# How to import .mat -v7.3 file in python using h5py BUT with same ordering of dimension?

Tags: python, h5py

I have several .mat files and each of them including a Matrix. I need to import them in python using h5py, because they have been save by -v7.3.
For example:

```
*myfile.mat  includes matrix X with the size of (10, 20)*
```

I use following commands in python:

```
*import numpy np,h5py
f=h5py.File('myfile.mat','r')
data=np.array(f['X'])
data.shape*    ->    **(20, 10)  Here is the problem!**
```

The matrix X is transposed. How can I import the X without being transposed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to live with transposing.  MATLAB if F ordered, numpy C ordered (by default).  Somewhere along the line `loadmat` does that transposing.  `h5py` does not, so you have to do some sort of transposing or reordering.

And by the way, `transpose` is one of the cheapest operations on a `numpy` array.

save a (2,3) array in Octave

```
octave:27> x=[0,1,2;3,4,5]
octave:28> save 'x34_7.mat' '-7' x
octave:33> save 'x34_h5.mat' '-hdf5' x
octave:32> reshape(x,[1,6])
ans =   0   3   1   4   2   5
```

load it.  The shape is (2,3), but if F ordered:

```
In [102]: x7=loadmat('x34_7.mat')

In [103]: x7['x']
Out[103]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.]])

In [104]: _.flags
Out[104]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  ...
```

Look at the `h5` version:

```
In [110]: f=h5py.File('x34_h5.mat','r')

In [111]: x5=f['x']['value'][:]
Out[111]: 
array([[ 0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  5.]])
# C_contiguous
```

and the data in `x5` buffer is in the same order as in Octave:

```
In [134]: np.frombuffer(x5.data, float)
Out[134]: array([ 0.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  2.,  5.])
```

so is the data from `loadmat` (though I have to transpose to look at it with `frombuffer` (to be Ccontiguous)

```
In [139]: np.frombuffer(x7.T.data,float)
Out[139]: array([ 0.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  2.,  5.])
```

(Is there a better way of varifying that `x5.data` and `x7.data` has the same content?)

---

This pattern holds with higher dimensions. In MATLAB it's the 1st dimension that varies most rapidly.  Loaded by h5py, that dimension corresponds to the last.  So a `x(:,2,2,2)` would correspond to a `x[1,1,1,:]`, and a `x.T[:,1,1,1]`.